# how does data mining technique AdaBoost work?

Tags: database, data-mining, adaboost

I came across the data mining technique AdaBoost but i can not find much information regarding how it works or any examples i can go through, can someone please shed some light in this area?

Also i would like to give prediction and exploration of data a try, does anyone have any examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/inst/ag-ki/adaboost4.pdf) explains the idea very well. At the end of the tutorial, in section **Problems**, item 4 points you to a simple classification problem which you can try, and item 5 points you to the code of the implementation of the Viola-Jones algorithm in the
OpenCV library. Its object detection framework employs a variant of the AdaBoost to both select the best features and to train classifiers that use them.

Comment: forgive me for my ignorance, but how does this algorithm differ from say neural networks which also has a set or weights, an error calculation and recalculation of weights?

Comment: Boosting is an ensemble learning method. Usually it is constructed at a higher level after you have some underlying classifiers working. If the underlying classiers are linear networks, then AdaBoost
builds multilayer perceptrons one node at a time. However, underlying classier can be anything. Decision trees,
neural networks, hidden Markov models.

Comment: do you have a simple example i can walk through?

Comment: how about this video? There is a simple example in it (starting at 20:01) http://videolectures.net/mlss05us_schapire_b/